# Comparar propriedades de um objeto com propriedades de uma lista

Tags: c#, .net, comparação, propriedade

Possuo um método:

```
public void MetodoAleatorio(List<RequisicaoFisicaDTO> lstRequisicaoFisicaDtos)
{
    RequisicaoFisicaDTO requisicao = lstRequisicaoFisicaDtos.FirstOrDefault();


}
```

Onde eu recebo uma lista de DTO e preciso verificar se algumas propriedades são iguais em todos os objetos recebidos, por exemplo:

```
lstRequisicoes.All(x => x.IdTipoObjeto == requisicao.IdTipoObjeto);
```

Eu tenho cerca de 12 propriedades desse objeto que precisam ser comparadas com a lista de objetos para que atenda ao que eu quero. Existe uma forma mais genérica de fazer isto? Ou uma forma melhor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim. [Uma vez respondi no SO gringo exatamente sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737975/how-to-check-that-which-properties-entries-are-modified-and-which-are-not-on-edi/). Abaixo vou postar um método de extensão para trazer as propriedades diferentes entre dois objetos. Basta você adaptar à sua lógica:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Extensions
{
    public static class ModelExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ValoresDiferentes<T>(this T obj, T modifiedObject) 
        {
            foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
            {
                if (property.GetValue(obj).ToString() != property.GetValue(modifiedObject).ToString())
                {
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(modifiedObject));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seria algo assim:

```
var valoresModificados = requisicao.ValoresDiferentes<RequisicaoFisicaDTO>(requisicaoDaSuaLista).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

[Nessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844855/221800) eu achei algo que é mais ou menos o que deseja.

Tem que pensar se compensar usar isto, tem que usar muito.

É mais lento e menos confiável. Talvez precise adaptar alguma coisa, quem sabe inverter a situação da lista para ignorar se na maior parte do tempo a lista a ignorar for grande demais.

Tem outras implicações, se mudar a estrutura do objeto pode mudar o comportamento deste método e dar resultados diferentes do que espera.

```
public static bool PublicInstancePropertiesEqual<T>(this T self, T to, params string[] ignore) where T : class {
    if (self != null && to != null) {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var ignoreList = new List<string>(ignore);
        var unequalProperties =
            from pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            where !ignoreList.Contains(pi.Name)
            let selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(self, null)
            let toValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(to, null)
            where selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !selfValue.Equals(toValue))
            select selfValue;
        return !unequalProperties.Any();
    }
    return self == to;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/ComparingListMembers.cs).